What is the "strife" that makes a city strong in "Oedipus"?
In Oedipus Tyrannus, after Jocasta reveals to Oedipus that Laius was killed where "three roads meet", Oedipus begins to freak out, beginning to realize that it was indeed him who killed the late king. The Chorus then goes into their ode, which includes these lines:

But the healthy strife that makes the city strong—
I pray that god will never end that wrestling:
god, my champion, I will never let you go.
Oedipus the King, Ode 2, translation by Robert Fagles (1982), lines 969-971

I'm assuming that "god" here refers to Zeus, but I'm not quite sure what the "healthy trife" may be that makes the city "strong". Strife is generally not considered a good thing, and it seems like an odd word choice here. I could maybe understand "disagreements" keeping the city strong, in the vein of democracy, but "strife" has stronger and more negative connotations.
Is this just an odd choice by the translator that's not reflected in the original Greek? In any case, what kind of strife or disagreement might this be referring to that makes the city strong?

This is lines 880–881:

τὸ καλῶς δ᾽ ἔχον
πόλει πάλαισμα μήποτε λῦσαι θεὸν αἰτοῦμαι.
I beg the god never to rescind the wrestling that brings good to the city
Sophocles (c. 429 BCE). Oedipus Tyrannus, lines 880–881. My translation.

Here πάλαισμα is a bout or a fall in a wrestling match. Fagles, as is often the case, has translated the word twice: literally as “wrestling” and figuratively as “strife”. θεὸν just means “god”; sometimes it can mean a specific god such as Zeus, but here the sense “any god; all the gods” seems more likely. Lewis Campbell says (page 211) that here θεὸν is “generalized more completely than elsewhere in Sophocles.”
In this passage the chorus are contrasting two kinds of civic competition or rivalry: the bad kind (ὕβρις, insolence or outrage), that leads to tyranny, and the good kind (πάλαισμα, a wrestling bout), that benefits the state. Wrestling is a contest governed by rules, not a lawless brawl.
Here’s a selection of critical notes:

In the antistrophe the Chorus indulges in reflections upon the direful consequences of a spirit of lawlessness, when developed in the ruler of a state, and calls to mind, in contrast, the patriot, who strives only for his country’s weal; it prays God never to suffer this spirit of patriotism to be lessened, and professes an unshaken confidence in Him.
John Williams White (1875). Note to line 873. In The Oedipus Tyrannus of Sophocles, page 131. Boston: Ginn.


It is needless to suppose any particular reference or allusion in these words; which simply denote the striving of patriotic zeal as distinguished from the struggles of lawless ambition. ‘May God never end the contention that is for the city’s good.’
Lewis Campbell (1879). Note to Oedipus Tyrannus, lines 879–880. In Sophocles, volume 1, page 211. Oxford: Clarendon.


but the struggle which is honourable to the city (that of the good against the bad citizens, in defence of the divine laws), I pray that the god may never abolish.
T. H. Steel (1885). Note to lines 879–882. In Benjamin Hall Kennedy, editor (1885). The Oedipus Tyrannus of Sophocles, page 115. Cambridge: Deighton, Bell.


I see θεὸν and  θεός used in various texts, but always wondered what, if any, is the difference between them (I'm not a native Greek speaker). A quick search reveals θεός is singular (God), meaning that theon would only be used in the plural form (gods)?

@josephh θεός is masculine singular nominative; θεόν is masc. sing. accusative. "Gods" is θεοί, θεούς, etc. See Wiktionary's Ancient Greek grammar tables.
